# Single Xbox controller is detected as second controller

Tags: windows-8.1, game-controller

On Windows 8.1 my Xbox controller is detected as secondary, the Microsoft button on the controller lights up number 2.

When I test it in control panel everything is fine. But games such as Rayman don't detect it this way.

This usually happens after putting my laptop to sleep and changing the USB devices.
Restarting the computer resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before - I think it's just an issue that's there.

There are 2 ways that might work instead of having to restart your PC;

1. Unplug the controller and reconnect it
2. Unplug the XBox wireless receiver and reconnect it

They have worked for me in the past - so hopefully you'll have luck.

Comment: These are the first things that one would try out - with no luck. And my controller is wired.

Comment: I'm not sure then - Sounds like it may just be an issue that you'll get with Microsoft. Did you try unplugging it before you sleep the laptop? Then plug it back in after?

Comment: Tried. But why does it happen? What is detected as the first controller (probably its old instance)?